# Мультиклиентское мультисерверное приложение

Tags: c++, linux, клиент-сервер, проектирование

Мне нужно написать клиент серверное приложение у которого будет много клиентов>100 и будут сервера. За сервером будут закрепленны определенные клиенты. Сервера будут общаться между собой.  Сделать это я хочу на с++ под linux пока думаю про qt. Но с какой стороны подступиться сейчас вообще не представляю. Проект это "учебный", по этому чем больше своих костылей тем лучше, но все равно хочу сделать все "правильно" и "по науке". Сейчас в поисках литературы про архитектуру таких приложений. Может вы знаете опен сорс проекты с похожей системой на чей код можно посмотреть.

**upd. 1**

Представьте себе клиент сервеное прложение чат, но серверов много под каждую конференцию свой Сервер. И если кто-то пишет слово "Фазенда", об этом узнают во всех чатах.

Comment: для начала составьте точное ТЗ. Что будут делать клиенты, чем обмениваться, чем сервера будут обмениватся. А потом можно взять какой-нибудь irc сервер/клиент и смотреть, как это все сделано.

Comment: клиент соединяется с ip адресом сервера. Этот ip он узнает из DNS. что бы клиент пришел на нужный сервер ему dns должна отдать правильный ip. для этого клиент должен запросить некое уникальное имя домена что бы по нему, ему лично дали нужный ip. Либо, если dns имя будет общее, то скорее всего будет нужен балансер нагрузки, который каким то образом узнает клиентов и кидает на нужный сервер (в web приложениях обычно такой подход используют)

Comment: Посмотрите книжку Шона Уолтона "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux". Там очень подробно всё расписано и множество примеров - и клиентских и серверных. Выберете в качестве "шаблона" наиболее подходящий вариант.